# How do I mock a component that has a 'ref' with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have some code like:

```
import { GoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';

const GoogleMapContainer = () => {
    const zoomToBounds = React.useCallback(
        (map): void => map && bounds && map.fitBounds(bounds),
        [bounds]
    );


    <GoogleMap ref={zoomToBounds}>
        ...
    </GoogleMap>
}
```

and am trying to mock the `GoogleMap` with jest when I am testing `GoogleMapContainer`

```
jest.mock('react-google-maps', () => ({
      GoogleMap: (props) => <div>{props.children}</div>,
}));
```

However, I get an error like:

```
    Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

I am unable to use `forwardRef` because jest complains about using functions from outside the scope. I get the same error if I try to create mock class-based component for GoogleMap.

How do I get around the `ref` error?

Answer (score 2):

In answer to my own question.

You can refer to external variables in your mock if you start their name with `mock`. Then you can require the containing class after the mock, guaranteeing that the external variable (`MockGoogleMap`) is set.

```
class MockGoogleMap extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(): ReactElement {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

jest.mock('react-google-maps', () => ({
  GoogleMap: MockGoogleMap,
}));
const GoogleMapContainer = require('./GoogleMapContainer').default;
```